# Chose type of element in a struct at runtime in C

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, runtime

I am currently recoding objdump for a school project and I have a problem.

In fact, I have a struct which contain an element that can be of two different types depending on if the file passed to the program is 64 or 32bits and I'm trying to find a way to chose the right type at runtime instead of duplicating my struct (and code) for the two cases.

The struct:

```
   typedef struct          s_elf
    {
      Elf64_Ehdr            *ehdr; //Should be Elf32_Ehdr * for 32bits
      Elf64_Shdr            *shdr; //Should be Elf32_Shdr * for 32bits
      unsigned int          len;
    }                       t_elf;
```

The goal here is to be able to access those elements regardless of their type like so

```
t_elf elf;
elf->ehdr->e_shoff;
```

I've tried many thing including nested union, void * and cast, external struct, etc but nothing seemed to work.

Is it possible to do that in C ? If yes, how ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: not sure if there is better solution, but I would add type member to struct, or create something like this: `struct Elf {int type; unsigned int len; void* ehdr; void* shdr;}` or use unions. But you need to modify your functions to handle both cases differently, because i think than length of `Elf64_*` and `Elf32_*` structs will be different

Comment: With a statically typed and compiled language like C it's not possible. You can work with preprocessor macros and [C11 generics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) to *write* less code, but in the end there will still be multiple copies of basically the same code.